# Web Analytics Reports - Top Pages per user?

Tags: web-analytics

The *Web Analytics Reports* that come with SharePoint 2010 are great. Especially the *Top Pages* report. However, I have a situation where **I would need the *Top Pages* report but on a *per-user* basis**. Is it possible to customize this report somehow to achieve this?

If I customized the *Top Pages* report, I can see that the Data Connection used to generate the report contains certain fields. I'm new to this and don't know how I would add a field to the Data Connection - or even whether the data I want is even collected.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint's basic web analytics reports are ok but they don't show details or anything custom, so you won't be able to see Top Pages by Username.

The information you want to see is contained in the IIS logs.  You can find the folder that contains the logs by looking at the Site ID for the site collection, and then finding the "W3CSVC(siteid)" folder under the IIS logs directory.

Once you have the logs, you'll need to process them in a Log Parser-type utility.  There are also some commercial web analytics software options for SharePoint which will work.  The right choice depends on your budget.